# JAVA - sorting a linked list by descending order

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

i tried to write a method that sort a linked list.
this is java training for me.

the method should get a linked list with values and sort it with **selection sort.**
**but** not the usual selection sort, but selection sort that find the biggest number and put it in the start of the linked list. until the list is sorted.

i tried follow the debugger but, i cant really understand what i did wrong.

this is what i tired:

```
public IntList selectionSort()
{
    IntNode tempMax = _head;
    IntNode current = _head;
    IntNode fromHere = null;
    IntNode toHere = _head;
    IntNode prev = null;
    while(toHere != null)
    {
        current = toHere;
        tempMax = toHere;
        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current.getNext() != null && current.getNext().getValue() > tempMax.getValue())
                {
                    prev = current;
                    tempMax = current.getNext();
                    current = current.getNext();
                }
            else current = current.getNext();      
        }
        prev.setNext(prev.getNext().getNext());
        tempMax.setNext(toHere);            
        if (fromHere == null)
            _head = tempMax;
        else fromHere.setNext(tempMax);
        fromHere = tempMax;
        toHere = fromHere.getNext();
    }
    return this;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just move the values inside a `IntNode` rather than moving `IntNode` around.

Comment: Could you put in some comments into your code? I'm having a hard time keeping track of which variable is used for what.

Answer (score 1):

A few tips:

- If you want the smallest number then `current.getNext().getValue() > tempMax.getValue()` should have a `>` instead of a `<`
- Your code will also fail if the first element is already the minimum value, as you try to do something to `null`
- I can see duplicated code in here too, `current = current.getNext()`.  Pointer operations are generally hard to code, and writing clearer code sticking to the principle of Don't Repeat Yourself will probably help you see bugs!
- It will help people here help you if you print compiler/runtime error messages

Comment: i know, but i want to sort from biggest to smaller.

Comment: that's not what you say in the description

Comment: `if the first element is already the minimum value...` yes use `>=`

Answer (score 1):

The main issue with your code, is that it misbehave when a node is already at the position it should be. If we execute with :

`5 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3-> 4`

`prev` will be null and we crash.

If we do with :

`1 -> 4 -> 5 -> 3-> 2`

at the first iteration you obtain

`5 -> 4 -> 1 -> 3-> 2`

So far so good.And then, after the loop of the second iteration

`5 -> 4 -> 3-> 2` ***// prev still pointing at 4, 1 dissapears***

`5 -> 4 -> 4`.    ***// tempMax = toHere so tempMax->tempMax, and the other elements are gone***

So the manifestation is that `prev` is invalid in some way. 
There is a quick fix, like skipping the repositioning when `toHere` is the maximum,
but quick fixes are not what you need. You should :

- Rethink about some special cases. Empty list, one element, list already sorted, list sorted in reverse, random order, (duplicate element??)
- Write unit test for each case
- Rewrite your algorithm, and avoid ***Oh yes, I forgot the case...*** . Dumb it down, you only need to replace the first element at each given step with the maximum found at this step.
- Avoid variables which have redundant information. For example, `tempMax` should always be the next of `prev`, so `prev` alone is enough. Otherwise you are spending brain cells preserving consistency.
- Test again the suite case.